# Print set() item fill with python generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator:

```
foundUnique = set()
def unique_items(myList, index, clearFlag): 
    for item in myList:
        if clearFlag is True:
            foundUnique.clear()
            clearFlag = False
        if item[index] not in foundUnique:
            yield item
            foundUnique.add(item[index])
```

And I am using this `unique_items to get a unique list:

```
senderDupSend = unique_items(ip, 4, True)
```

Now I want my set to be reachable (I can print its element or do some changes on specific element .....) but when I write:

```
for item in foundUnique:
    print item
```

It prints nothing!

But if I write:

```
for item in senderDupSend:
    print item
for item in foundUnique:
    print item
```

It prints all foundUnique items.

Please tell what did I do wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @aaronasterling: Holy !! python surprises me all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `unique_items` is a generator so that

```
senderDupSend = unique_items(ip, 4, True)
```

is a generator that needs to be iterated over. When you run

```
for item in foundUnique:
    print item
```

the generator has not actually run yet so `foundUnique` is still empty.

When you later go on to do

```
for item in senderDupSend: # This is what actually fills the list.
    print item
for item in foundUnique:
    print item
```

It should print out the set twice: once while it is being constructed and once after it is constructed.

---

It seems like what you are trying to do is construct a set that has the same index taken from every element of some sequence. You can do it like this very easily:

```
found_unique = set(item[index] for item in sequence)
```

In the concrete case that you show, it would be:

```
found_unique = set(item[4] for item in ip)
```

If you later wanted to extend the set to contain other items, you could do

```
found_unique.union(item[4] for item in other_ip_list)
```

Comment: you right but I have 2 problem: 1- how can solve this issue  2- generator just make item over run just one time(or keeps the item they provide) why I can reach foundunique after iterate over senderDupSend.(when first for iterate it keeps value for foundunique? man I am confused by generator )

Comment: @Am1rr3zA The first problem is easy, use a generator expression passed to a `set` constructor as I illustrated. For the second one, a generator will only run over its values once. In this case, you are having the generator leave the values in `foundUnique` so that they will be available after (but not before) the generator runs.